# Save custom field on WP_List_Table

Tags: php, plugin-development, custom-field, wp-admin, wp-list-table

I have a custom field which is named `clicktripz_object_location`. I've created a WP_List_Table with the following code;

```
if(is_admin())
{
    new UCO_Wp_List_Table();
}

/**
 * UCO_Wp_List_Table class will create the page to load the table
 */
class UCO_Wp_List_Table
{
    /**
     * Constructor will create the menu item
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'add_menu_uco_list_table_page' ));
    }

    /**
     * Menu item will allow us to load the page to display the table
     */
    public function add_menu_uco_list_table_page()
    {
        add_menu_page( 'Custom UCO', 'Custom UCO', 'manage_options', 'clicktripz-custom-uco.php', array($this, 'list_table_page') );
    }

    /**
     * Display the list table page
     *
     * @return Void
     */
    public function list_table_page()
    {
        $exampleListTable = new UCO_List_Table();
        $exampleListTable->prepare_items();
        ?>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div id="icon-users" class="icon32"></div>
                <h2>Custom UCO</h2>
                <?php $exampleListTable->display(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}

// WP_List_Table is not loaded automatically so we need to load it in our application
if( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

/**
 * Create a new table class that will extend the WP_List_Table
 */
class UCO_List_Table extends WP_List_Table
{
    /**
     * Prepare the items for the table to process
     *
     * @return Void
     */
    public function prepare_items()
    {
        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = $this->get_hidden_columns();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

        $data = $this->table_data();
        usort( $data, array( &$this, 'sort_data' ) );

        $perPage = 2;
        $currentPage = $this->get_pagenum();
        $totalItems = count($data);

        $this->set_pagination_args( array(
            'total_items' => $totalItems,
            'per_page'    => $perPage
        ) );

        $data = array_slice($data,(($currentPage-1)*$perPage),$perPage);

        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
        $this->items = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Override the parent columns method. Defines the columns to use in your listing table
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function get_columns()
    {
        $columns = array(
            'post_title'                 => 'Title',
            'post_date'                  => 'Date',
            'clicktripz_object_location' => 'Location'
        );

        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * Define which columns are hidden
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function get_hidden_columns()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Define the sortable columns
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function get_sortable_columns()
    {
        $sortable = array(
            'post_title' => array('post_title', false),
            'post_date'  => array('post_date', false),
        );

        return $sortable;
    }

    /**
     * Get the table data
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    private function table_data()
    {
        $post_data = get_posts( array(
            numberposts => -1
        ));

        $page_data = get_pages();

        $data = array_merge( $post_data, $page_data );

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Define what data to show on each column of the table
     *
     * @param  Array $item        Data
     * @param  String $column_name - Current column name
     *
     * @return Mixed
     */
    public function column_default( $item, $column_name )
    {
        switch( $column_name ) {
            case 'post_title':
            case 'post_date':
                return $item->$column_name;
            case 'clicktripz_object_location':
                return '<input type="text" value="'.$item->$column_name.'">';

            default:
                return print_r( $item, true ) ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows you to sort the data by the variables set in the $_GET
     *
     * @return Mixed
     */
    private function sort_data( $a, $b )
    {
        // Set defaults
        $orderby = 'post_title';
        $order = 'asc';

        // If orderby is set, use this as the sort column
        if(!empty($_GET['orderby']))
        {
            $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
        }

        // If order is set use this as the order
        if(!empty($_GET['order']))
        {
            $order = $_GET['order'];
        }


        $result = strcmp( $a->$orderby, $b->$orderby );

        if($order === 'asc')
        {
            return $result;
        }

        return -$result;
    }
}
```

As you can see I've managed to put input boxes to custom WP_List_Table I've created.

[image: Custom WP_List_Table]

But I couldn't find to way a put a save button to the right lower corner of the page. Also how can I create a save function to save all the changes at once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I've found a way to get POST data from a form. Thanks to [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/) article, I've successfully managed to get the data from the my WP_List_Table through [admin_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) mechanism.